# Second implementation of async task without await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, interface

What can I do when I have an interface that returns a task (void) but one of the implementations has no async action?

My interface `IDatabaseService` has two implementations: `FirestoreDatabaseService` and `CacheDatabaseService`. It makes sense for `FirestoreDatabaseService` to use the Method `async Task AddResult(ResultDto result)` as result of a method but the `CacheDatabaseService` has only a `list` and needs no `await`, it is basically a `void` method.

I get a warning

> Warning CS1998    This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run
> synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await
> non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)'" when I implement the
> method in CacheDatabaseService async. If I remove the async I have to
> return a task but Task.FromResult does not work for void Tasks.

Comment: `return Task.CompletedTask;` (although `Task.FromResult(false)` *will* work as well, since `Task<T> : Task`)

Comment: This is only warning, you can choose to ignore it!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Task.CompletedTask is what I was looking for a long time. @phuzi I stopped ignore warnings and always make them to errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That warning almost always means your method should not be `async`.

The `async` keyword really just enables the use of `await`. So if you aren't using `await`, you don't need `async`.

If `AddResult` *must* return a `Task`, then return a `Task`. If you aren't actually doing anything asynchronous, then you can return [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?view=netframework-4.8).

For example:

```
public Task AddResult(ResultDto result) {
    ...
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

If you have to return a value (`Task<T>`), then you can use [`Task.FromResult()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.8).

An interface that specifies that a method should return a `Task` is just a way of making it *possible* to make the method `async`. It doesn't mean it must.

Comment: I believe the method names is `AddResult`.  `FirestoreDatabaseService` is the name of the class that does use async methods.

Comment: Yes, but the concept works - I was looking for that. I will mark this answer as the accepted solution as soon as I can. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's eerie how often I go searching for an answer, only to find one from a question that arose from the same source material. In my case, it was a Firebase-related IHostedService -- which requires an async StartAsync() method. But I had nothing async to implement in it. Appreciate the question asked here and the answer even more!